# Backup database in drive C cause an error

Tags: .net, vb.net, stored-procedures, backup

I have a question. Why is it i cannot backup my database in drive c using vb.net?

This is the messagebox error:

[image]

My Stored Procedure that i will execute in vb.net

`BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseNameTest TO DISK = '\\DSA02\Users\DSA_02\Source\Sample.BAK'`

But if i try this to another drive like:

`BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseNameTest TO DISK = '\\DSA02\DSA_02\Source\Sample.BAK'`

It will not cause an error.

So why is it in drive c my code return error while in another drive it does not.
Can any one solve or help me with this problem?

---------- Solution I've found ----------

Note: Not sure if this is the best answer/solution but now i can save my backup file in drive c.

I configure the Folder in `drive C User` where it will be save. Example: `C:\User\Destination` I configure the `Destination` Folder

Steps:

`Properties->Security Tab->Edit Button->Click Add->Enter object name like "Guest"->Click Check Names->Then OK->Then Click the newly added CompName/Guest field in "Group or Username"->Then Check All the Permission of Guest Except for Deny->Then OK.` Then this will now allow you to save file in `drive C` to its `Destination Folder` No need to run your program as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must open the Visual Studio as Administrator to do this.
then, go to the Project propieties and click in view Windows settings. You should see somthing like this:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Your should change this statement to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Close all, now Start as Administrator. The problem is that you cant write in `C:/` dir without Administrator privileges.

Comment: I cant replicate what you are trying to say. I cannot found the `View Window Settings` in `Project properties.` However i found another solution. See my edit above

Answer (score 0):

You have two directories listed in the message box above. Since you mentioned that you did this in VB.net, I'm guessing that you concatenated a string.

If you did something like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseNameTest TO DISK = ' C:\Users\DSA_02\Source\Sample.BAK'
```

You'll get that error. Notice the space between the first single quote and the C:\Users part.

If you're concatenating a string to a variable, try outputting the result to say a msgbox to see if it's concatenating correctly first.

Comment: i replace the error box. the first error is that the server sql is not reachable my drive c so i replace it by \\Computer name and so on. see my new error above